# Executing code asynchronously without the help of a second thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

OK first of all, it's nothing that I need to implement or anything. I just need to know the answer because someone more experienced told me that asynchronous execution doesn't necessarily have to involve a new thread as threads are somewhat heavy constructs, which confused me a lot and I couldn't agree.

Now let's say, I have two methods - `Execute()` and `ExecuteAsync()`. `Execute()` is running on the main thread. I want to call `ExecuteAsync()` from within `Execute()` and I don't care whenever it completes executing, but when it does, may be (or may be not) I want use it's return value. That's a typical example of an asynchronous execution, right?

I know I can do this using `BackgroundWorker` or `IAsyncResult` (`Delegate.BeginInvoke()`), but AFAIK under the hood they spawns a secondary CLR Thread/ThreadPool Thread.

So is it anyhow possible to execute the method `ExecuteAsync()` asynchronously without the help of a second thread?

**EDIT :** I think this edit will clarify the scenario further. Invoking `ExecuteAsync()` is NOT the only (or last) task for `Execute()` to perform. `Execute()` should continue it's own tasks without caring about the execution of `ExecuteAsync()` method.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: @I4V Still will (usually) use a threadpool thread, though.

Comment: Why don't you have a look at new features of c# and .NET 4.5? using async and await is what you are talking about. in addition, have a look at this. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows-Camp/Windows-Store-App-Development-for-iOS-Developers/Asynchronous-programming-with-C-

Comment: async/await just changes how you use the asynchronous operaiton - it doesn't change how they're (necessarily) implemented.

Comment: @I4V: AFAIK a Task itself uses a ThreadPool thread behind the scene

Comment: The link i provided here can lead to a good point of view abut how this works in new version (update) of .NET 4.5

Comment: @NerotheZero Not quite.  Only by default.  There are a number of ways of creating a task, some of which use a thread pool, some of which use a new (non-pooled) thread, and some of which use neither.

Comment: @NerotheZero u r welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a program that uses asynchrony and never ever uses more than one thread:

```
public class Foo
{
    private int _value;
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            var oldTCS = tcs;
            tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            oldTCS.SetResult(true);
        }
    }


    public Task ValueChanged()
    {
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.ValueChanged()
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(foo.Value);
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

    foo.Value = 5;
}
```

The `Task` returned from `ValueChanged` will be completed the next time that `Value` is changed.  The user of the `Foo` class can get that returned task and wire up continuations to run on that task based on an operation that has not yet happened.  Then, at some point in the future, the value of `foo` is changed, and the continuation will run.  Note that the foo object could be passed to some other function, entirely unknown to `Main`, that ends up setting the value (to show why you might want to do something like this).

No new thread is needed to create the `Task`, nor to execute the continuation.

Here's another example that's much more practical:

We'll start with this simple (extension) method that takes a form and returns a `Task` indicating when that form is next closed:

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static Task WhenClosed(this Form form)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        form.FormClosed += (sender, args) => tcs.SetResult(true);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Now we can have this in one of our forms:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Form2 otherForm = new Form2();
    otherForm.Show();

    await otherForm.WhenClosed();

    //take some data from that form and display it on this form:
    textBox1.Text = otherForm.Name;
}
```

Creating and showing another form never involves the creation of new threads.  Both this form and the new form use entirely the one UI thread to be created and modified.

The creation of the `Task` returned from `WhenClosed` does not need to create a new thread at all.

When the `Task` is awaited, no new thread is created.  The current method ends and the UI thread is left to go back to processing messages.  At some point, that same UI thread will do something that results in the second form being closed.  That will result in the continuation of the task running, thus returning us to our button click handler where we set the text of the textbox.

*All* of this is done *entirely* with the UI thread, no other threads have been created.  And yet we've just "waited" (without actually waiting) for a long running operation to finish (the user to put some information into the second form and then close it) without blocking the UI thread, thus keeping the main form responsive.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with "No new thread is needed to create the `Task`...". AFAIK, until .NET 4.0, a Task itself uses a `ThreadPool` thread under the hood.

Comment: @NerotheZero Until .NET 4.0 `Task` didn't exist, so obviously it couldn't be *anything* under the hood.  Post 4.0, (i.e., for the entire history of `Task`) some tasks result in the creation of a brand new thread, some involve a thread pool item running, and some involve neither.  I have shown two examples that fall into that last bucket of "neither".  A `Task` created from a `TaskCompletionSource` doesn't result in a new thread or thread pool thread, and tasks created from most IO calls don't utilize another thread either.  That's part of what make tasks *really* powerful.

Comment: Sorry i meant the 4.0 version of `Task` class introduced via in TPL

Comment: @NerotheZero There was no version of `Task` before the TPL.  The whole point of introducing the TPL was that it was the introduction of `Task`.

Comment: Sorry again, I meant exactly that `Task` class, first introduced in .NET 4.0. May be my "until .NET 4.0" was confusing to you. Anyway I didn't know using `Task` could result a `no-new-thread` scenario. Thanks for your explanation. It really helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> So is it anyhow possible to execute the method ExecuteAsync() asynchronously without the help of a second thread?

It is possible for some methods to run asynchronously without using a new thread.  This can be done via [Asynchronous I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) with a [signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O#Signals_.28interrupts.29), for example.  Most of the framework's new Async methods added in .NET 4.5 async IO whenever possible instead of threads.

This is why it's a good idea to not assume asynchronous == new thread.  While asynchrony can be implemented using threading, it is not always implemented this way.  It's better to just think of an asynchronous operation as an operation that (hopefully) will not block, and will complete at some point in the future.

Comment: @NerotheZero No - typically, asynchronous code that's CPU bound will use another thread.  You can do it via coroutines, or via mechanism's such as Servy's example, etc - though you're not running other work while the async operation is running in that case...

Comment: I see content of the links refers to I/O operations and lower level Interrupt signal which AFAIK are also used in I/O operations. Are you suggesting I should consider executing code on a processor an I/O operation?

Comment: @NerotheZero As I tried to mention - threading is one means of implementing asynchrony. That being said, if you're doing asynchronous CPU work, and you want to continue doing work in your main routine while the async work is occurring, you'll probably use threading.  If you're doing "general" async operations, it may or may not use threading.

Comment: Please consider the EDIT added. May be it'll narrow down the possibilities of different implementation scenario.

Comment: @NerotheZero THe main issue is, do you want `ExecuteAsync` to be running while the Execute method is still running?  If it's a CPU-based method, and you want it to run at the same time, it will use some form of threading internally to perform that.  If it's IO, it may not.  If you don't care if ExecuteAsync starts/runs immediately, the Servy's method will work without a new thread...

Answer (score 1):

[Coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) are a common way to implement several logical threads using a single physical thread. Older operating systems used this and other related concepts to implement [cooperative multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking#Cooperative_multitasking.2Ftime-sharing).

In this context you may also be interested in [continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) and [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) has a good blog series on this very topic - [Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/21/continuation-passing-style-revisited-part-one.aspx), [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/22/continuation-passing-style-revisited-part-two-handwaving-about-control-flow.aspx), [Part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/25/continuation-passing-style-revisited-part-three-musings-about-coroutines.aspx), [Part 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/26/continuation-passing-style-revisited-part-four-turning-yourself-inside-out.aspx), [Part 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/27/continuation-passing-style-revisited-part-five-cps-and-asynchrony.aspx).

Comment: That's really interesting!